# Prove that Markov numbers has all the solution to the Markov Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

We know that given the Markov Diophantine equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=3xyz$ we have a solution $(x,y,z)$ then markov show that $(x,z,3xz-y)$ and $(y,z,3yz-x)$ are also solutions, using them we can build a tree which begin at $(1,1,1)$.

My question is the following, how can I prove that those are all the integral solution for the equation?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article [Markoff number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number)?

Comment: @Somos Yes I did, I'm trying to show that every number that is a solution to the equation is one of those I wrote(The markov numbers).

Comment: Did you read the part where it states "This graph is connected; in other words every Markov triple can be connected to (1,1,1) by a sequence of these operations.[1]"?

Comment: @Somos its stil not a proof that every number can begin at $(1,1,1)$ and using markov we can get all the rest

Comment: Did you read the footnote reference "Cassels (1957) p.28" which most likely contains a proof?

Comment: @Somos did you notice that there is no link to this? and cannot be found at the internet?

Comment: @Somos there is a very complete discussion in http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf  which is a good source for this site about "Vieta Jumping." Proofs are complete. There are enough equations that the German is relatively easy; full disclosure, i took German in school.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the great information! I can read mathematical German. Would you like to put that into an answer for this question?

Comment: @Somos I put a brief answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best source on this is [HURWITZ 1907](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf). A proof for the Markov numbers is included. Lots of students on this site are aware of a contest technique called "Vieta Jumping." The improvement that Hurwitz gives is to emphasize the geometry of "fundamental solutions" of one of his diophantine equations, where we just need to show existence of solutions obeying some fairly tight inequalities. For this direction, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vieta-jumping